# SVG not rendering on new page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, svg, ionic4

I have SVG hexagon avatar that works fine on one page but then when I move to another page the svg is not being rendered.

For example, on the **first page** the avatar works correctly:

[image]

but then after navigating to another page the SVG is no longer rendering:

[image]

I have the avatar SVG in its own component called `hex-avatar`.

`hex-avatar.component.html`:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 166.59 167.72">
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1 {
            fill: none;
        }

        .cls-2 {
            clip-path: url(#clip-path);
        }</style>
        <clipPath id="clip-path" transform="translate(6.84 0.23)">
            <path class="cls-1"
                  d="M149.26,41.68c5.1,6.35,4.56,77.73.16,83.63s-64.09,41.86-72.35,41.95S8.43,132.85,4.57,125.59-3.34,52.77,4.41,42,67.8,0,76.75,0,144.16,35.32,149.26,41.68Z"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
        <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
            <g class="cls-2">
                <g id="NXRQAU">
                    <image id="NXRQAU-2" data-name="NXRQAU" width="600" height="600" transform="scale(0.28 0.28)"
                           [attr.xlink:href]="url"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

You can see from above the image inside of the hexagon is an input into the component:

```
export class HexAvatarComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() url: string;
```

Why is the hexagon svg not rendering on the avatar when routed to a new page (component)?

Comment: I imagine the non-working page has more than one element with id="clip-path" All id values must be unique on a page.

Comment: @RobertLongson negative. The first page has multiple as well

Comment: So they are both invalid but the first one randomly works even though it's invalid too.

Comment: You need to make sure that all the `id` attributes on any page are unique.  If you have multiple `id="clip-path"` on the page you will get weird results based on the order of the elements and perhaps even which browser you are using.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau shouldnt that not matter since its in its own component and shadow dom? like I said it works great on the first page which also has multiple avatars

Comment: @RobertLongson i tried making the clip path a unique name using random numbers and it still didn't work. not sure why that would be a problem anyway because of the shadow dom